# Need a standard way to add a project to visual studio and make it work with other projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am making a project file called `Business`.  I have a website project file as well.  I want to be able to access the classes in the `Business` project in the website project.  What are the necessary steps in order to make all the right references and includes so that I can successfully use classes from another project.  Also, if I want to be able to use the `Business` project file to access database features do I need a separate web.config file in order to put the connection strings?  If so are there necessary steps in order to make a web.config file work with the `Business` project, such as references etc.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the Business project to your Website project's solution.
Then add the Business project as a reference to your website project using the "Add reference" option.
When you see the "Add reference" dialog box, switch to the "Projects" tab and you'll see the business project listed there.

As regards connection strings in web.config file...
The Website project is the "Application", the Business project is an assembly. If you have a Data project, then that's an assembly as well. What you need to know/understand here is that assemblies don't have app.config/web.config files. They automatically use the "config" file of the "Application" that uses them.

So in other words, your Website project will need to have the connection string in the web.config file. None of the other "library" projects should have or need to have a "config" file of their own.

When the application runs (in this case your Website application) and it uses the services of the Business assembly, the business assembly will automatically "see" the web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

It's smart to break apart the domains in your solution to enable the sort of reuse you alluded to. Personally, I typically have one project representing my client (your web app in this case) and other projects that the client depends on (specifically, added as project references). You may consider two other projects in your case, one that encapsulates the database connectivity and the models in your database and another that encapsulates higher order business objects (if you have any).

Once you have things broken out, you can simply add them as project references from within in the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

typically, one creates a solution that contains several (or one) different projects, then adds reference to the projects.

so, for example, you have one solution with a "business" project and anther project that contains the web site, which you add a reference to the business project/assembly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click the Solution (at the top of Solution Explorer) and select Add -> New Project and select `Class Library`. This will create a new project which you can call 'Business'.
2. Then right click your original project and select 'Add Reference ...'. Under the 'Projects' tab on the window that then pops up you'll see the class library project you just created. Select it and click 'OK'.

Just repeat step 2 for any other projects which need to use the class library.

You can put your connectionstrings in the web.config of your web site project root directory.

HTH.